# Modelling Countries and Cities

Tags: django, django-models

I'm currently learning Django, and I'm trying to model countries and cities.  A country has many cities, out of which one (and only one) is a capital city.  I've come up with this so far:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
```

How can I incorporate the capital city part into the model?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could to use a recursive model, example:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    place_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    is_capital = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

To create countries, states, cities...

```
country = Place()
country.name = 'Ecuador'
country.save()

state = Place()
state.name = 'Pichincha'
state.place_parent_id = country.id
state.save()

city = Place()
city.name = 'Quito'
city.place_parent_id = state.id
city.is_capital = True
city.save()

city2 = Place()
city2.name = 'Other city'
city2.place_parent_id = state.id
city2.is_capital = False
city2.save()
```

Explanation: Ecuador has 24 states and each state has cities, the previous example mean say:

```
country     state       city
------------------------------
Ecuador / Pichincha / Quito
Ecuador / Pichincha / Other city
```

Comment: This solution and explanation is fantastic.  Thank you very much for putting time into the question I posted.